# Get the two last parts of an IP address in PHP

Tags: php

I'd like to get the two lasts octets from an IP address with PHP.
I tried this :

```
substr(strrchr($ip,'.'),2);
```

But it seems I misunderstood the code, since it's not working... (eg. if my IP is 192.168.0.79, this line returns only "9"...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can [explode](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.explode.php) the ip string and get the parts from it.

```
    $ip = "192.168.0.79";
    $split = explode(".", $ip);
    $part1 = $split[2]; // 0
    $part2 = $split[3];// 79
```

Comment: @CaptainHarlock, this answer is what you need!

Comment: @CaptainHarlock you are welcome! Can you mark it as answer?

Answer (score 4):

Using your solution, just change `2` with `1`:

```
substr(strrchr($ip,'.'),1); // Output 79
```

Comment: he/she wants parts as octets, not as a string.

Comment: No, I meant, I want to output "0.79" in that case

Comment: @CaptainHarlock, edit your question please! You want to output the last two octets of the IP!

Answer (score 2):

If you want last part as **string**, use `explode` with 3rd parameter:

```
$parts = explode('.', '192.168.0.79', 3);
echo $parts[2];    // "0.79"

// or even:
echo explode('.', '192.168.0.79', 3)[2];    // "0.79"
```